# Push objects into empty array, return filled array in instance variable. - RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays

This seems so basic, but I'm having trouble figuring this out. I have this method:

```
def index
  @stores = Store.all
  @my_deals = []

  @stores.each do |s|
    if current_user.voted_for?(s)
      @my_deals.push(s.deals)
    else

    end
  end

end
```

If a user has `voted_for` a store, that stores deals should be pushed into the `@my_deals` array. I want to use the filled `@my_deals` array in the view, however it currently just returns `[]`. I'm guessing it grabs the variable before the code below runs to fill it. How can I use the `@my_deals` **after** it's been filled?

Comment: are you sure it _has_ been filled? it should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `deals` is array you can push it, you should add elements one by one.

```
@stores.each do |s|
  if current_user.voted_for?(s)
    s.deals.each { |d| @my_deals << d }
  else

  end
```

Comment: Perfect! That worked, but why was the array empty with my code above? I'll accept in 1 min.

Comment: Can't say, maybe it's not loading deals and it works when iterating through them.